# Blender 2.80 Cycles light wont render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

[Download Project - BlenderScene100.blend - Blender 2.80](https://mega.nz/#!Nwglhaha!NSIIR8Vih6hvLhz60O8tPpPCh_3ZcZUQoCQey7xKpAc)

I was playing around with blender 2.80 when I made the scene above, whenever I render lights just disappear, I can't show you what its supposed to look like as whenever I take a screenshot the lights disappear -

[image: Lights are supposed to appear but they don't]

I have no idea why this is happening, any help?

Comment: For future reference, we prefer if .blends are uploaded [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/599). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your file, except that the light sources are really dim. If you look closely in your screenshot, you can even see a faint reflection. Note that you have volumetric scattering on, which will make things dimmer than they would be otherwise.

Things you can try:

- Increase the emission strength of the spot lamp (a lot, for [some reason spot lamps tend to be dimmer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14567/599)).
- Increase the emission strength of the emission shader on `Cylinder.001`.
- Increase the emission size of the spot lamp. This won't make it brighter, but it will help it converge faster.
- Increase the exposure in *Properties > Render > Color Management*.

Comment: Huh, that's odd, when I took the screenshot 5 days ago, everything was pitch black, now I can see it. I revoke my question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the fact, that my light had an animation on it. When I have deleted this animation, everything was fine!